# vNext AspNet.Identity custom password validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I add custom password validation? I can some things via the view but I'd rather add some custom validators to the controller and/or model to not allow the last 5 passwords to be used.  Any pointers would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first step you would have to keep a history of the user passwords whenever they change it.

Since the passwords are hashed you would have to use IPasswordHasher to hash the provided new password before you could compare it vs previous password hashes.

If you are using the standard project template with identity and the provided ManageController, you could add a dependency for IPasswordHasher in the constructor and then you could add logic in the ChangePassword method of the controller or implement a helper class that has the logic to hashed the new password and determine if it exists in the stored previous hashed passwords.

Then if you determine the user is trying to re-use one of the previous password you could add an error to modelstate:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You cannot re-use previous passwords");
return View(model);
```

that would give you server side validation.